CCXT - load markets for exchange OneTrading
I am trying to use python library ccxt to retrieve public data (e.g. available markets) from crypto exchange OneTrading.
I created an API key with read-permissions.
Somehow, ccxt retrieves an empty dict. Why is this?
This is my example code:
from pprint import pprint
import ccxt

api_key = "<redacted>"

creds = {
        'apiKey': api_key,
        'verbose': True,  # for debug output
    }

exchange = ccxt.onetrading(creds)
pprint(exchange.requiredCredentials)  # prints required credentials
exchange.check_required_credentials()  # raises AuthenticationError

pprint(exchange.load_markets())

Output:
{'accountId': False,
 'apiKey': True,
 'login': False,
 'password': False,
 'privateKey': False,
 'secret': False,
 'token': False,
 'twofa': False,
 'uid': False,
 'walletAddress': False}

fetch Request: onetrading GET https://api.onetrading.com/public/v1/currencies RequestHeaders: {'User-Agent': 'python-requests/2.31.0', 'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate', 'Accept': '*/*', 'Connection': 'keep-alive'} RequestBody: None

fetch Response: onetrading GET https://api.onetrading.com/public/v1/currencies 200 ResponseHeaders: {'Date': 'Sat, 11 May 2024 07:34:44 GMT', 'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Content-Length': '2', 'Connection': 'keep-alive', 'apigw-requestid': 'XmHfOicWDoEEPOg=', 'strict-transport-security': 'max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains', 'x-frame-options': 'sameorigin', 'x-xss-protection': '1; mode=block', 'x-content-type-options': 'nosniff', 'referrer-policy': 'no-referrer', 'Cache-Control': 'no-store', 'pragma': 'no-cache', 'bp-request-id': '6e914827-43be-4fb8-9b52-cd9d93caadaa', 'CF-Cache-Status': 'DYNAMIC', 'Server': 'cloudflare', 'CF-RAY': '88207cfe9cb49722-AMS'} ResponseBody: []

fetch Request: onetrading GET https://api.onetrading.com/public/v1/instruments RequestHeaders: {'User-Agent': 'python-requests/2.31.0', 'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate', 'Accept': '*/*', 'Connection': 'keep-alive'} RequestBody: None

fetch Response: onetrading GET https://api.onetrading.com/public/v1/instruments 200 ResponseHeaders: {'Date': 'Sat, 11 May 2024 07:34:44 GMT', 'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Content-Length': '2', 'Connection': 'keep-alive', 'apigw-requestid': 'XmHfQjFgjoEEPFA=', 'strict-transport-security': 'max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains', 'x-frame-options': 'sameorigin', 'x-xss-protection': '1; mode=block', 'x-content-type-options': 'nosniff', 'referrer-policy': 'no-referrer', 'Cache-Control': 'no-store', 'pragma': 'no-cache', 'bp-request-id': '7aee16cb-fc32-47bc-b8c5-60f2d8fa54e1', 'CF-Cache-Status': 'DYNAMIC', 'Server': 'cloudflare', 'CF-RAY': '88207d002e889722-AMS'} ResponseBody: []
{}


After some more research I found that there is already an open issue on github:
One Trading - API Domain Change #21098
Apparently, some contributors are already working on it, so hopefully they can provide a fix soon.
